# Report a bug badge?

Tags: discussion, badge-request

I found a bug/broken link.  Does SOF have a badge for reporting bugs? The link below:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=asp.net-identity-2&sort=featured

Comment: This isn't a bug report, and what exactly do you mean by "reward"?

Comment: Your reward is the warm feeling you get by helping SE improve their platform, and perhaps some free Internet points.

Comment: Please don't use **EDIT** in your posts.  We don't really need to know that you edited your posts in the first four minutes; just fix them.  After the first five minutes, there's an edit history we can all look at.

Comment: haha, I'll drink to that.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no badges given out for bug reports.

If you find a serious security bug, you will be mentioned in the [security hall of fame](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) though.

I would also not class this as a bug - a feed link to a non-existing tag gives back an empty feed, sounds right to me.

Comment: I think you should manually trawl through any potential broken links (including made up ones) and return a 404, do not automate this, it will ruin the fun. (I totally get the reason the feed is blank btw)